# system function works on R and does not work on rstudio/shiny

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I'm running ubuntu, and when I use R command line interface the system function works:

```
system("./script.sh")
```

But when I do the same on rstudio, I have the messages:

```
./script.sh: line 3: program: command not found
```

the program on line 3 is on my path and works fine from command line, do I have to set some environment variable on rstudio/shiny?

Answer (score 0):

Check Sys.getenv('PATH') and if necessary Sys.setenv('PATH') or you could use the full path.

Remember that Shiny apps will have a path relative to where they are launched.

**Addition**

Since your running Ubuntu you could also try setting the path in `~/.Renviron` or `/etc/R/Renviron`

Comment: Thanks @oskar, using the full path for 'program' inside the sh script allows rstudio to find it. But then the 'program' has a dependence that is not found, can I include the path on some variable?

Comment: You could try `addResourcePath` or `includeScript` is it packages or scripts you want to include?

Comment: scripts written in python. What I don't understand is why I have access for example to system('pwd') and not to my script, where do I set this and why it works on R command line and not rstudio?

Comment: Is it in Rstudio or shiny that you have this problem?

Comment: I think that in shiny the webroot is set to the directory the app launches in

Comment: My problem is the same in both rstudio/shiny, I made it work now using the full path for all scripts used, but I'm still not happy. I undestand that shiny uses the app directory, but I want it to be able to use the system applications too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92996/discussion-between-oskar-forsmo-and-user1265067).